# Visual Studio Intellisense documentation for javascript and complex object description

Tags: javascript, object, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'm trying to describe in and out object parameters.
I have a method that gets an object as parameter and I want to describe it for intellisense so the team can have intellisense enabled when they are using the libraries I am working on.

```
    var getSomething(element, params) {
            /// <summary>Function summary</summary>
            /// <param name="element" type="jQuery">Valeur textuelle permettant le groupage</param>
            /// <param name="params" type="Object">{autoCreate:boolean, sSomething:string}</param>
    };
```

How to describe "params" content with Intellisense for Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Since intellisense is provided by your IDE, the syntax depends on what IDE you're using. The most common however is derived from a tool that outputs generated documentation, JsDoc (http://usejsdoc.org/)

For example, to be recognized in the IntelliJ family (WebStorm, PhpStorm), your example could be written like this:

```
/**
 * @param {jQuery} element Valeur textuelle permettant le groupage. PS: You need to define jQuery somewhere else
 * @param {Object} params
 * @param {boolean} params.autoCreate
 * @param {string} params.sSomething
 */
var getSomething = function(element, params) { // (your previous syntax was invalid)
};
```

My advice is too look into the documentation of your IDE for help.

Comment: I meant intellisense for Microsoft Visual Studio. I use JSDocs as well, and it works well, but that's not supported by intellisense by Microsoft as they have a notation that is different (they're using the tripple slash /// and it's within the function).

Comment: I know they're different. I will leave the answer up for people not using VS. Good luck with getting an answer that helps you!